# PHP Usort in a parent static class with callback in the calling static class

Tags: php, oop, usort, static-classes

I have a "static class" used as a singleton (because there's never a need to have multiple instances), and other classes that extend it and are used in the same way.

At some point in the processing, the extended class will call parent::doThis(), with doThis ultimately doing a usort.

The callback of the usort should be in the calling class, as each will handle sorting differently. Can something like "class::method()" be the string for a usort callback, and if so, is there a way for the parent class to know which class called it without me passing that as an argument, so that it can name the calling class's callback for the usort?

```
class parentClass {
  protected static function doThis($data) {
    // do stuff, then
    usort($data, "myCallingClass::cmp()"
  }
}
```

based on some means of the parent determining what myCallingClass is, or does it need to be

```
class parentClass {
  protected static function doThis($data, $calling_class) {
    // do stuff, then
    usort($data, $calling_class . "::cmp()"
  }
}
```

Comment: both solutions should work, but if u need to put different callbacks, then use #2 so u can always switch between callbacks

Comment: Was something wrong with the question? I see it was downvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this with [Late Static Bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php):

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) {return(static::cmp($a, $b));});
```

Comment: Would be nice this way, but not implemented in php yet.

Comment: @georg What isn't implemented? Late static binding has been in PHP since 5.3 (~5 years).

Comment: It's referenced [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

Comment: Just tried it. In the parent, I have public static function p() {print 'hello';} and public static function test() {static::p();} and then in the extended class public static function p() {print 'goodbye';} and invoking self::test() in the extended class results in 'goodbye';   Haven't tried it with the usort yet... is That what's not implemented?

Comment: If usort doesn't take the static callable directly, you may need to wrap it in a closure:

`usort($data, function($a, $b) {return(static::cmp($a,$b));});`

Comment: I've confirmed that this works as expected with the closure / callable wrapper, answer edited.

Comment: @AlpineCoder: yes, this way it works in php 5.6 (not in older releases, see [bugreport](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66622))

Comment: @georg I just tested this on OSX / PHP 5.5.14 and it works as expected.

Comment: Oh, right, my 5.5 was way too old... Thanks for fixing!

Answer (score 2):

you can add `static function name() { return "myCallingClass"; }` to each class with it's own name. Then all you need is to call

```
usort($data, static::name() . "::cmp()");
```

`static` modifer assures you that method will be called from inheriting class if it has one.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to use a well-known callback name in combination with [`get_called_class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php):

```
class Numbers
{
    static function sort() {
        $things = [1,2,3,4,5];
        usort($things, [get_called_class(), 'cmp']);
        print join(' ', $things);
    }
}

class Mod2 extends Numbers {
    static function cmp($a, $b) {
        return $a % 2 - $b % 2;
    }
}

Mod2::sort(); // 4 2 5 3 1
```

A not-so-simple, but correct solution is to forget all this "static classes" and "singletons" stuff and use objects the way they are intended to be used:

```
class Numbers
{
    function sort() {
        $things = [1,2,3,4,5];
        usort($things, [$this, 'cmp']);
        print join(' ', $things);
    }
}

class Mod2 extends Numbers {
    function cmp($a, $b) {
        return $a % 2 - $b % 2;
    }
}

(new Mod2)->sort(); // 4 2 5 3 1
```